# jQuery selector for an href without a class

Tags: jquery

How do I change this selector to only call my function if the target does NOT have a specific class on it ('noscroll' as shown below)?

```
$('a[href^="#"]').live('click', navigation.smoothScroll);

<a class="noscroll" href="#">My Link</a>
```

Something like this (psuedo code):

```
if (!($this).hasClass('noscroll'))
   ($this).live('click', navigation.smoothScroll);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.not()`

```
$('a[href^="#"]').not('.noscroll').live('click', navigation.smoothScroll);
```

Answer (score 1):

use the [:not() selector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)

```
$('a[href^="#"]:not(.noscroll)').live('click', function () {
  //your code here
});
```